# Mapstruct - generic mapper

Tags: java, mapstruct

I wnoder how can I avoid DRY (don't repeat yourself) in my case:

I want to have two mappers: one converts `Road` to `RoadWithLUPlaceDto` and second `Road` to `RoadWithLUPlaceSmallDto`.  `RoadWithLUPlaceSmallDto` just has less fields than `RoadWithloUnPlaceDto` I don't want to have two interfaces with the same `qualifiedByName` methods with logic.

`RoadWithLUPlaceSmallDto` has a field `RoadAddressSmallDto`, NOT `RoadAddressDto` so I can't reuse the same methods marked by `qualifiedByName`. How can I do that? Is it possible?

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MyMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "lPlace", source = "road", qualifiedByName = "PointToLPlace")
    @Mapping(target = "uPlace", source = "road", qualifiedByName = "PointTouPlace")
    RoadWithloUnPlaceDto map(Road road);

//    @Mapping(target = "loadingPlace", source = "road", qualifiedByName = "SpotToLPlace")
//    @Mapping(target = "uPlace", source = "road", qualifiedByName = "SpotTouPlace")
//    RoadWithLUPlaceSmallDto mapToRoadWithLUPlaceSmallDto(road road);

    @Named("PointToLPlace")
    default RoadAddressDto mapLPlace(Road road) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(road)
                .map(road::getPoints)
                .filter(point -> !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(points))
                .flatMap(
                        points-> points.stream()
                                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Point::getOrder))
                                .filter(point-> isAllowed(point.getOperations(), OperationType.L))
                                .findFirst()
                ).map(this::mapRoadAddress)
                .orElse(null);
    }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

MapStruct supports using meta annotations for `@Mapping`. So in your use case you can do something like:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Mapping(target = "lPlace", source = "road", qualifiedByName = "PointToLPlace")
@Mapping(target = "uPlace", source = "road", qualifiedByName = "PointTouPlace")    
public @interface CommonRoadMapping { }
```

and then use that in your mapper

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MyMapper {

    @CommonRoadMapping
    RoadWithloUnPlaceDto map(Road road);

    @CommonRoadMapping
    RoadWithLUPlaceSmallDto mapToRoadWithLUPlaceSmallDto(road road);

    @Named("PointToLPlace")
    default RoadAddressDto mapLPlace(Road road) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(road)
                .map(road::getPoints)
                .filter(point -> !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(points))
                .flatMap(
                        points-> points.stream()
                                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Point::getOrder))
                                .filter(point-> isAllowed(point.getOperations(), OperationType.L))
                                .findFirst()
                ).map(this::mapRoadAddress)
                .orElse(null);
    }
...
```